# How can I change the docker subnet in Windows Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, networking, docker-for-windows

I understand that docker desktop creates a VM host for my containers to run.
When I run `docker inspect {container_name}`, I can see my container has an address of `172.x.x.x`.

I use a subnet `172.16.0.0/13` for lab networking, and so I've found that any time I try to ping the container from my windows host, the traffic goes out my lab nic, as I would expect.

I'm aware I could add a route to send traffic to the virtual nic that is created to contact the VM host, but this would conflict with my custom subnet.

How can I make docker use IPs outside of my local subnet? I believe if I could get my containers to use `172.24.0.0/16`, then I could add a custom route to funnel traffic from my windows host to the virtual docker host.

Comment: Does the setting described in [What is the “Docker Subnet” used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62849480/what-is-the-docker-subnet-used-for) work for you?

Comment: I wasn't sure how that is used since its a different subnet than the IPs that come up (`192` vs `172`). I read somewhere that is an internal setting, and I don't see any routes related to that subnet on my windows host.